# DatabaseReference 'setValue' Android Studio shows error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first use firebase, I follow the steps, but I cannot run

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

and error text

```
2020-06-02 14:48:51.664 28968-29015/com.example.chatapp E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
```

The error appears on the **second line** and early time appears in **the third line**.

The firebase rule has been changed to true.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code? If you think it's related to your security rules, include the minimal security rules with which you can reproduce the problem in your question too.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add it on the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your "message" node includes sub-nodes or sub-values, you can't use setValue directly for this node. You should clear contents of this node.